# SQL Syntax for Assertion to count the number of Employees from "Department"

Tags: mysql, sql

```
EMPLOYEE(ssn, emp_name, salary, dept_no)
DEPARTMENT(dept_no, dept_name, mgr_ssn)
```

Part of an "understanding" exercise we have for our database class now that everything's shut down is to write a... "generic" assertion statement that checks the number of employees under each department to be less than 40.

We JUST started on Assertion statements and I'm kind of helplessly lost.

```
CREATE ASSERTION <Employee.count_40>
CHECK ((SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM EMPLOYEE > 40) 
    NOT DEFERRABLE;
```

I know I need to create the assertion, count the rows (using COUNT(*) and... then everything gets a bit shaky. I'm still learning SQL syntax as well, but I think I have the syntax *here* okay.

Any help at all would be appreciated greatly!

EDIT: We are using MySQL, though... this is supposed to be some sort of "generic" statement. I'm not sure what our professor meant with this as I don't believe there is a "generic" form of SQL?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports asserts.  You would need to use a trigger or check constraint.

Comment: We are using MySQL.

Comment: Mysql does not support assertions, so there is absolutely no way to make your statement work in mysql. Period. As @GordonLinoff suggested, you can use a trigger instead.

Comment: @ProgrammingYote87 . . . There is not a "generic" SQL, but there is Standard SQL, described by ISO Standard 9075.  Most databases distinguish themselves by their differences from the standard.